# How i center an image at Ipad

Tags: html, css

i am new here thanks in advance.

How i can center align top slider images in ipad right now images are left align.

please see link below,

http://psd2htmlexpert.com/examples/Baytreefloristhtml/

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

To center an image you can use this snippet:

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

Images are inline elements as a default so you need to make it a block element before you adjust the margins.
The `auto` simply devides the margin on each side of the element and thus end up in the middle.

*(I added the width: 80%; since it cannot be equally wide as it's parent because then there will be no margins left to divide.)*

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wfLGG/5/)

Comment: i already add this but its not working.

.top_slideshow .slidesbox img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}